# Absolute positioning and responsive divs

Tags: html, css

I'm making a responsive site with a banner image in an absolutely positioned div, then another absolutely positioned div that overlaps it using z-index properties for text set on top.

This causes the footer to vanish below these elements. As the divs above are responsive, I can't use the margin property on later divs to stop them displaying below the absolutely positioned elements. I'm wondering what the simplest way to get round this is, and hoping somebody can point me in the simplest direction!

HTML:

```
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
    </div>

            <div id="bannerdiv">
                <div id="largebanner">
                <img src="images/large-banner.jpg"; width: 2304px; height: 800px;>
                </div>
                <div id="mediumbanner">
                <img src="images/medium-banner.jpg"; width: 1152px; height: 400px;>
                </div>
                <div id="bannertext">
                    <p id>tester</p>
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div id="footer">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
img { height: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%;}
body {width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;}

#nav  {text-align: center;}
#header h1 {text-align: center;}
#bannerdiv { height: auto; position: relative; }
#largebanner { z-index: 1; position: absolute; }
#mediumbanner { z-index: 1; position: absolute; }
#bannertext { position:absolute ; z-index: 10; margin: 40px 0 0 40px;}
#footer {float: left; position: relative;}
li {
display: inline;
padding: 0.5em;
}

#nav, #footer {
background-color: #efefef;
padding: 0.5em 0;
position: relative;
}


@media all and (min-width: 1201px) {

#largebanner {display: block; z-index: 1;}
#mediumbanner {display: none;}
}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) 
{
#largebanner {display: none;}
#mediumbanner {display: block;}
}
```

Comment: If you link your code you wrote so far you will have more chance to get answer as it is easier to understand the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a framework like bootstrap?

Also, for footers vanishing below the elements, the header, body and footer needs to be encased in a div to prevent that from happening.

It would be nice if I can see the problem in action, so I can understand it more.

Comment: Thanks to all who have volunteered help so far, code now added!